# Different textSize of TextView's using autosize despite having the same conditions

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview, scale

I have a ConstraintLayout with 2 AppCompatTextview's with exactly the same text. I am using `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` attribute to autoSize the textSize according to the width and height of the AppCompatTextview's (the width and height of the AppCompatTextview's is 0dp so that it fills the space that is determined by the constraints). I have tested the app and I have used the layout inspector and I have seen that both AppCompatTextview's have exactly the same width and height but different textSize and baseline.
AppCompatTextview 1:

> height: 23dp width: 100dp baseline: 60 textsize: 15,7 sp

AppCompatTextview 2:

> height: 23dp width: 100dp baseline: 61 textsize: 16 sp

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/AppCompatTextView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_acc"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_acc"
        android:text="@string/ttx"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="2dp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/re1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/re2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/re3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/re4"
        />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/AppCompatTextView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_acc"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_acc"
        android:text="@string/ttx"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="2dp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/le1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/le2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/le3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/le4"
        />
```

I don't understand why if the width and height is the same, the textSize is different.

I have also noticed that the TrandformPivotY is different in both...

Comment: It would help if you could provide the full layout with the text you are using. Also which device/emulator. In the meantime, check the height/width of the views in pixels (not dps) to see if it is a rounding thing.

Comment: @Cheticamp I have discovered that the problem is caused because a difference of only one pixel, In some devices this difference doesn't exist and in others yes. I have thought that it could be happening because if the total pixels of all the ConstraintLayout are an odd number, some elements will have one more pixel than the others as if there are an even number of elements, an odd number can't be dividied into an even number of elements, do you think that this could be causing the problem as always the problem is caused by just one pixel?

Comment: I think that might be the problem. I'm not sure how you discovered this; Can you even see the difference one pixel makes? If you want to test your theory, you can force the same size on the relevant elements by adding one pixel to some element, margin or padding. Alternately, if you are so inclined, you can use the debugger to check values in the underlying code that computes the font size.

Comment: @Cheticamp I have finally found a solution, I have answered my own question with a solution that is apparently working, thanks for guiding me to the solution, I have been so many days with this problem :)

Comment: @Cheticamp as you can see in my answer, I think that the problem is not that the total pixels of all the ConstraintLayout are an odd number, the problem is because the total pixels of all the ConstraintLayout dividied by the number of elements is not an exact division. Do you think it sounds good? Does my answer make sense?

Comment: It does looks good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had is that the TextView's had different height size in pixels (one pixel of difference only). I have investigated my layout and I have seen that the problem was caused because all the available pixels of my Constraint Layout dividied by the number of elements wasn't an exact division (remainder equals zero) (note that if it is not an exact division, one element will have one pixel more). What I have done to solve this is really simple:

**First-->**
Get the available pixels: to do this, what I have done is to calculate all the height pixels of the ConstraintLayout and subtract those pixels that were fixed(the height of those elements which has "height = Xdp" instead of 0dp where X is not equal to 0)(Also if some element had margin, that margin should be also subtracted).

**Second-->** Once I have calculated the available pixels, what I have done is to divide it by the number of elements until the remainder of the division equals zero.

```
  int h=0;
  while(availablepx%num_of_elemets!=0){
   availablepx--;
   h++
   }
```

**Third-->** Now that the number of pixels that have to be added to the layout(h) have been calculated, the only thingto be done is to add those pixels as margin of some element of the layout.

Thanks to @Cheticamp that guided me to the solution.